# possible Hex map permutations or combinations with a 7 hex layout

Tags: algorithm, math, game-development

I'm curious if anyone can assist me with this gaming question. I'm looking for the most accurate answer/algorithm for the total possible permutations/combinations for a 7 piece hex map based on the following criteria:

A single stationary central hex which can rotate to any of its six possible orientations, surrounded by six hexes that can rotate to any of their six possible orientations, and each of those outer hexes can be located adjacent to any side of the central(hub hex).

Comment: Share your thoughts. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: At I'm Curious. This is a test of the overflow math brains that might wish to try at a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The central hex can be rotated to 6 different states.

```
6
```

The other 6 hexes can be placed around the mid one in 6! ways.

```
6 * 6!
```

Each of the outer hexes can be rotated to 6 different states.

```
6 * 6! * 6*6
```

The final answer is

```
6^7 * 6!
```

which means there are 7 hexes that can b rotated to 6 different states and there are 6 different hexes that can be placed around the center one.

This answer assumes that all of the hexes are different and rotating the whole setup makes a different setup.

Comment: All hexes are different though only the central cannot move other than being rotated. Is the answer 1,679,616 based on sudomakeinstall2's formula?